# Returning the text from a selection using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For the following page:

http://www.aidn.org.au/Industry-ViewCompany.asp?CID=3113

I have the following scrape code:

```
findit = soup.find_all("td", "Page-Headers", align="left")
print findit
```

which returns the following:

```
[<td align="left" class="Page-Headers" valign="middle">Aerospace Materials Pty Ltd</td>]
```

Good so far.

How do I get it to return the text element ("Aerospace Materials Pty Ltd") from this pattern using BeautifulSoup? Or is the best way to simply regex on this output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `getText`

```
for td in soup_result:
    print td.getText()
```

Or as pointed out by @Zero Piraeus for `bs4` you should use `.get_text()`

Comment: @Zero Thanks for comment - shows how long ago it's been since I used BeautifulSoup!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.string`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) property:

```
>>> for el in findit:
...   print el.string
... 
Aerospace Materials Pty Ltd
>>>
```